# $this object reference for nested custom objects in Powershell

Tags: powershell, scripting

There's something that I can't quite seem to wrap my head around when trying to do object references in Powershell. Not sure if there's something that I am missing out on.

A sample code illustrating this problem is as follows:

```
function Create-Custom-Object {

    $oResult = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property (@{
        "Test"          = $(Get-Date);
    })

    Add-Member -memberType ScriptMethod -InputObject $oResult -Name "GetTest" -Value {
        return $this.Test;
    }

    return $oResult
}

function Create-Wrapper-Object {

    $oObject = $(Create-Custom-Object)

    $oResult = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property (@{
        "Object"             = $oObject;
        "Test"               = $(Get-Date);
    })

    Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -InputObject $oResult -Name "WrapTest" -Value {
        return $this.Object.GetTest()
    }

    return $oResult

}

$oCustom = Create-Custom-Object
sleep 5
$oWrapper = Create-Wrapper-Object
echo "Custom-Test: $($oCustom.Test)"
echo "Wrapper-Test: $($oWrapper.Test)"
echo "GetTest: $($oCustom.GetTest())"
echo "WrapTest: $($oWrapper.WrapTest())"
```

When run, the output is as per below:

```
>powershell -file test.ps1
Custom-Test: 11/20/2017 16:10:19
Wrapper-Test: 11/20/2017 16:10:24
GetTest: 11/20/2017 16:10:19
WrapTest: 11/20/2017 16:10:24
```

What puzzled me is that the call to WrapTest() on the wrapper object returns the "Test" attribute value from the wrapper object instead of the embedded custom object. Why is Powershell behaving like this?

Comment: Both date objects in the Create-Wrapper-Object function get created within a second of each other. Add a `sleep 1` just after `$oObject = $(Create-Custom-Object)` and you'll see there is a one second difference.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the problem here (based on the assumed intent of the `sleep 5`) is that `$oCustom` is assigned a *Custom-Object* and then 5 seconds later `$oWrapper` is assigned a *Wrapper-Object* which contains a **new** *Custom-Object* with essentially the same `[DateTime]` value (to the nearest second), not the (intended?) previously created `$oCustom`. `WrapTest()` is not returning the `Test` member of `$oWrapper` but the indistinguishable `Test` member of its own *Custom-Object* in `$oWrapper.Object`. In order to create a (generic) wrapper object, you need something to wrap, otherwise it's really just a (specific) nested object. Something like this:

```
function Create-Wrapper-Object {
param ($ObjectToWrap)

  $oResult = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property (@{
    "Object"             = $ObjectToWrap; # presumably with a GetTest() method
    "Test"               = $(Get-Date);   # remember the time of wrapping
  })

  Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -InputObject $oResult -Name "WrapTest" -Value {
    return $this.Object.GetTest()
  }
  return $oResult
}
```

With the (assumed to be) desired result:

```
$oCustom = Create-Custom-Object
sleep 5
$oWrapper = Create-Wrapper-Object $oCustom
echo "Custom-Test: $($oCustom.Test)"
Custom-Test: 05/31/2021 08:52:30
echo "Wrapper-Test: $($oWrapper.Test)"
Wrapper-Test: 05/31/2021 08:52:35
echo "GetTest: $($oCustom.GetTest())"
GetTest: 05/31/2021 08:52:30
echo "WrapTest: $($oWrapper.WrapTest())"
WrapTest: 05/31/2021 08:52:30
```